# Lock app with password

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In WP application we need to provide user option to lock app with password.

As I understand WP app lifecycle, I need to put navigation to LockPage in App.Application_Activated, App.Application_Deactivated and start page, but I can not use NavigationService in App class...

I do not want to put navigation code to lock page in each other pages, or there is no other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I writed own solution, but may be it is not so elegant as it could be.

App locking logic: User enable app locking with password, we handling Application_Deactivated and Application_Closing events in App class and marking app as locked if user enabled this option. Then, on each page we should put check: is app currently locked and if it is, we should navigate to AppLockedWithPasswordPage. On AppLockedWithPasswordPage we need to check user`s password, if it is correct call NavigationService.GoBack().

So we need to do 6 steps:

1. You should choose where to save *IsAppCurrentlyLocked* (bool flag), *AppLockPassword* (string) and *IsUserEnabledAppLockWithPassword* (bool flag). I had chosen IsolatedStorageSettings
2. Create AppLockedWithPassword page, where you need to show TextBox and Button, do not forget to provide option for user to reset AppLock of course with deleting app data
3. AppLockedWithPasswordPage should  prevent BackButton navigation, so preventing it:

   ```
   // AppLockedWithPasswordPage
   protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
   {
       // Preventing back key navigation
       e.Cancel = true;
   }
   ```
4. Check password on button click

   ```
   // AppLockedWithPasswordPage
   private void UnlockAppButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (PasswordBox.Password.Equals(IsolatedStorageSettings["AppLockPassword"]))
       {
           NavigationService.GoBack();
       }
       else
       {
           // Say user, that password incorrect, etc...
       }
   }
   ```
5. In App class find Application_Deactivated (to handle app minimizing (windows button)) and Application_Closing (to handle when user closing app) methods, we should mark app as locked if user enabled this option when this events happens

   ```
   private void SetIsAppCurrentlyLockedFlagIfUserEnabledAppLocking()
   {
       if ((bool)IsolatedStorageSettings["IsUserEnabledAppLockWithPassword"])
       {
           IsolatedStorageSettings["IsAppCurrentlyLocked"] = true;
       }
   }

   private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
   {
       SetIsAppCurrentlyLockedFlagIfUserEnabledAppLocking();
   }

   private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
   {
       SetIsAppCurrentlyLockedFlagIfUserEnabledAppLocking();
   }
   ```
6. And final step, on all pages you want to lock you should add check in OnNavigatedTo method which will navigate to AppLockedWithPasswordPage if app is currently locked

   ```
   // Create some class, like PagesUtils or so on with check method
   private static Uri uriToAppLockedWithPasswordPage = new Uri("pathToAppLockedWithPasswordPage", UriKind.Relative);

   public static void NavigateToAppLockedWithPasswordPageIfAppLocked(PhoneApplicationPage page)
   {
       if ((bool)IsolatedStorageSettings["IsAppCurrentlyLocked"])
       {
           page.NavigationService.Navigate(uriToAppLockedWithPasswordPage); 
       }
   }

   // In each page you want to lock add
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       PagesUtils.NavigateToAppLockedWithPasswordPageIfAppLocked();
       base.OnNavigatedTo();
   }
   ```

P.S. of course real code is much better, this is just simple example, I hope it will help you

Comment: I'd use a base class for your pages to call `PagesUtils.NavigateToAppLockedWithPasswordPageIfAppLocked()` so you don't have to add it on every page.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the check in the `Application_Launching` and `Application_Activated` events.

The launching event for when the app is first opened and the activated one for when the user returns to the app after having left to do something else.

Have these events both set a flag and have the base page that all your pages inherit from check for this flag when navigated to. The check should be for if the flag is set, if it is, show the login prompt and then clear the flag after successful password entry.
This approach will handle FAS, FAR & deep linking, in addition to starting the app normally.

**Beware** Some choosers will trigger the activated event when they return to the app. Add extra handling for these as appropriate / if necessary.

Comment: I am handling Application_Deactivated and Application_Closing events and setting flag that app is locked, and then on each page I have check, that will open LockPage if flag is true

Comment: @ArtemZinnatullin Are you just saying that you've done what I recommended, or is there another question in your comment? If my answer addresses your question you should accept the answer and upvote.

Comment: No, I was wanted to say, that Application_Launching and Application_Activated events are not usefull, because I can not put navigation code to AppLockedWithPassword page in this events. As you can see, I has solved my problem and has written own answer

Comment: @ArtemZinnatullin I didn't say use those events to trigger navigation. I said to use them to track when to show the password prompt or not. Just as you're doing with closing and deactivated events.

Answer (score -1):

Why not create a start page where the passwords is entered?

For instances you have your MainPage.xaml, create a InsertPasswordPage.xaml reference it on WMAppManifest as the start page:

```
  <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="InsertPasswordPage.xaml" />
```

And insert all the password logic on the InsertPasswordPage.xaml, when the user successfully logins just navigate to your main page ;)

EDIT: As Gambit said if the user pressed the back button he will return to the insert password page, but you can solve this by removing from the backstack the page after the user logged in.

Comment: Problems with this approach is that when the user hits the Back button from MainPage, he will encounter the password page again.  Also, if the user jumps out of the app from some arbitrary page, when they jump back into the app, the password page will not display to block them.

Comment: Wrong, you can take the page from the back stack resolving that problem. thanks for the tip thougth edit the post ;)

Comment: Removing the page from the back stack will not resolve the problem of a user jumping out of the app via the Home button, and then returning into the app via the Back button.  Even in this app switching scenario, the user will need to be blocked by the password page.

Comment: Gambit please read my edit, only removed from backstack AFTER the user logged in. Now it depends on the use case, if the app is suspended the pass should be showed or not, depending on the case, the remove from backstack can be used or not

Comment: not sure you understand the scenario. If your backstack looks like: Login->MainPage->Page2->Page3->Page4, now the user switches out of the app.  When he returns to the app, the backstack is restored, the app will want to put him on Page4. But he should be immediately blocked with the login page. Removing or not removing the login page from the backstack does not address this scenario.