# Windows Phone: Forward to different screen when app wakes up after sleep/phone lock

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, sleep, tombstoning

I've developed a windows phone 7 app that I once a user locks the phone whilst running the app, when the phone gets unlocked that the app must forward the user to a different .xmal page.

The reason being is that the app displays sensitive information. So if the user locks his/her phone while in the middle of the app and leaves it on the table, nobody can come and just unlock the phone and see the sensitive information.

So I'd like to forward the user to a "Enter pin" page that I've already created.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476449/lock-app-with-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the [app activation and deactivation flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). You need to handle all your preparation for the user in this case in the application activation event, that is triggered when the app is pushed from dormant to active state.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
// This code will not execute when the application is first launched
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    this.AddEventLogItem("Application Activated event");
    // load application transient state when it is activated again
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, just a question though. Can I call this method from any .xaml.cs file?

Comment: Nevermind, I see you should just look for the pre-defined method in App.xaml.cs